# Jetbrains RubyMine - Font Configuration: How can I specify the *weight* of editor font?

Tags: fonts, configuration, rubymine

*Source Code Pro* by Adobe is my favorite monospace code everywhere. This font works best when it's on "light" weight instead of "regular". However I haven't been able to find anywhere in Ruby Mine the option to set font weight. Am I missing something?

Comment: Wanted a similar option in JetBrains Webstorm, as a work around, I removed all the other variants of the font except the one I wanted and that worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not possible. Please vote for [IDEA-109338](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109338)